# How do you pass a PointCollection instantiated in a .cpp to a Polygon in an .xaml?

Tags: c++, xaml, canvas, uwp, polygon

I'm trying to draw a polygon in a canvas using user supplied values. The rendering is fine given default values in the .xaml. My problem arises when trying to set the value of the Polygon Points property from the .cpp. I'm super new to UWP and I figured I could just set Points equal to a PointCollection, but that doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be great

Where the Canvas and Polygon are created in the .xaml

```xml
<Canvas x:Name="tCan" Margin="396,48,88,146">
       <Polygon x:Name="triangle" Stroke="Black"/>
</Canvas>
```

Passing PointCollection to 'Polygon triangle' in the .cpp

```cpp
By = 100 + a;
Cy = ((a * a) + (c * c) - (b * b)) / (2 * a);
Cx = sqrt((c * c - (Cy * Cy)));

PointCollection points;
points.Append(Point(100, 100));
points.Append(Point(100, By));
points.Append(Point(Cx, Cy));

triangle->Points = points;
```

that last line throws

```
"Windows::UI::Xaml::Shapes::Polygon::Points::set" cannot be called with the given argument list  
argument types are: (Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::PointCollection)  
object type is: Windows::UI::Xaml::Shapes::Polygon ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means the type of **triangle->Points** and **points** do not correspond,so you should convert the type of **points** :

```
By = 100 + a;
Cy = ((a * a) + (c * c) - (b * b)) / (2 * a);
Cx = sqrt((c * c - (Cy * Cy)));

PointCollection^ points = ref new PointCollection();
points->Append(Point(100, 100));​
points->Append(Point(100, By));​
points->Append(Point(Cx, Cy));​

​triangle->Points = points;
```